# How do we get the complex frequency of an exponentially damped sinusoidal function?

Tags: ac, frequency, alternatives

In my textbook, **Engineering Circuit Analysis 8.Ed by William H. Hayt (Chapter 14, Section 14.1 page 536)** I stumbled across a section explaining the complex frequency. The goal is to cover the concept of complex frequency when it comes to exponentially damped sinusoidal functions.

[image: complex_frequency]

HOW DID THIS HAPPEN?

1. How did \$e^{\sigma t}\$ become \$e^{j\sigma t}\$ out of the blue?
2. And why did \$e^{j(\omega t)}\$ become \$e^{j(j\omega t)}\$ ? 
   Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you take another look at your questions? There appears to be no difference between the two things...the original and the "become" version.

Comment: @elliotAlderson I just edited it.

Comment: It looks all screwed up.

Comment: @Andyaka It really does. Here is a picture of the section for you to see: https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZPPlg7ZngPpIC2dhafb9scO3EVjpHvok5py

Comment: You should post that pic in your question to give it authenticity.

Comment: Have you tried googling to see if that error has been found before?

Comment: @Andyaka Which error? I don't see one, off-hand. It looks straight-forward to me. The questions asked by the OP look wrong. But not the quoted book material.

Comment: @jonk the error mentioned in the op's question.

Comment: @Andyaka Perhaps I don't understand the OP's question. Give me a minute. I'll write up what I think is going on. Maybe I just misunderstand.

Comment: @jonk you're the turn-to guy for getting to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, there it is. Did I make a mistake there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first start by proving the first replacement. Do take note that \$\operatorname{cos}\left(-x\right)=\operatorname{cos}\left(x\right)\$ and that \$\operatorname{sin}\left(-x\right)=-\operatorname{sin}\left(x\right)\$:

$$\begin{align*}
e^{j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}&+e^{-j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}\\
e^{j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}&+e^{j\left(-\omega\,t-\theta\right)}\\
\left[\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)+j\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)\right]&+\left[\operatorname{cos}\left(-\omega\, t-\theta\right)+j\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(-\omega\, t-\theta\right)\right]\\
\left[\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)+j\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)\right]&+\left[\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)-j\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)\right]\\
\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)&+\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)\\\\&= 2\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)
\end{align*}$$

Obviously, this equivalent is true:

$$\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)=\frac12\left[ e^{j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}+e^{-j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}\right]$$

So, this means the first two lines of the quoted text appears correct:

$$\begin{align*}
v\left(t\right)&=V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t}\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega\, t+\theta\right)\\\\
&=\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t}\left[e^{j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}+e^{-j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}\right]
\end{align*}$$

Now I will go in tiny steps below, so there is no mistaking the simple algebra involved:

$$\begin{align*}
v\left(t\right)&=\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t}\left[e^{j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}+e^{-j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}\right]\\\\
&=\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t}\:e^{j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}+\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t}\:e^{-j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}\\\\
&=\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t+j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}+\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t-j\left(\omega\,t+\theta\right)}\\\\
&=\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t+j\,\omega\,t+j\,\theta}+\frac12 V_m\:e^{\sigma\,t-j\,\omega\,t-j\,\theta}\\\\
&=\frac12 V_m\:e^{j\,\theta}\:e^{\sigma\,t+j\,\omega\,t}+\frac12 V_m\:e^{-j\,\theta}\:e^{\sigma\,t-j\,\omega\,t}\\\\
&=\frac12 V_m\:e^{j\,\theta}\:e^{\left(\sigma+j\,\omega\right)t}+\frac12 V_m\:e^{-j\,\theta}\:e^{\left(\sigma-j\,\omega\right)t}
\end{align*}$$

This seems too easy. So did I completely misunderstand your question?

Comment: Was just about to hit submit with a similar derivation. Basically I think the OP forgot the rules of exponential

Comment: @jonk You completely understood the question. I also had the same line of logic as you. So I guess it's just a typo and I will email the editor about this.

Comment: So the extra j was wrong and the document linked was wrong. +1 for extended effort.

Comment: Hold on... are you saying the math looks kosher? I’m confused, you can’t agree with the error and imply the math is kosher at the same time hee hee

Comment: @Andyaka I'll remove that comment as confusing. Sorry about that. The derivation is sufficiently clear and there's no need for words that may muddle it.